# svn export will return "non-existent in that revision" error

Tags: svn

I am trying the following:
svn export http://svn.mySvn.net/scripts/python/testScript.py/tags/0.0.1 ./testScript.py/tags/0.0.1

And I get:
svn: URL 'http://svn.mySvn.net/scripts/python/testScript.py/tags/0.0.1' doesn't exist

When I do this:
svn list http://svn.mySvn.net/scripts/python/testScript.py/tags/

I get the folder:
0.1.1/

What is the problem? A bug?

Thanks.

Comment: Ah, and when I do: svn export h t t p://svn.mySvn.net/scripts/python/testScript.py ./testScript.py
it exports fine with all the sub-directories.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned

When I do this: svn list http://svn.mySvn.net/scripts/python/testScript.py/tags/

I get the folder: **0.1.1**

However, you're trying to access folder **0.0.1** in the URL:

'http://svn.mySvn.net/scripts/python/testScript.py/tags/0.0.1'

Is the folder you're trying to access 0.1.1 or 0.0.1?

Comment: Aha! Sh*t! Sorry. My bad. You are absolutely right. Embarrassing :) It works. I can not believe I have made that mistake.